# Ansible throws error with ini_file module if section is null

Tags: ansible

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using version: ansible [core 2.15.3]

I have a playbook with the following task:

```yaml
  - name: Ensure fav=juice is in file
    community.general.ini_file:
      path: /home/lab/test.conf
      section: null
      option: fav
      value: juice
```

When I run the playbook, I get the error

> "msg": "argument 'section' is of type <type 'NoneType'> and we were unable to convert to str: 'None' is not a string and conversion is not allowed"

If I change the section from `null` to any other string, it works. But as per [`ini_file` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html), `null` is permitted for section.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/b71b216ffe5d05d67d2af8a3441eba4a)

Comment: Ok, I was able to reproduce with `pip install --upgrade ansible==7.0.0 && pip install --no-dependencies --upgrade ansible-core==2.15.3`, to actually be in a situation similar to https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/6708

Comment: ^-- So, in order to be exhaustive and reproducible, you should [edit] in your question the result of `ansible-galaxy collection list community.general`

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, but, this is just a hole in the documentation that is in the process of being covered already:

> Originally `section` was required and `null`/`none` had to be passed to tell the module not to use a section. This stopped working with ansible-core 2.15.0 since then `null`/`none` are no longer accepted for `str` options; see [#6404](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/pull/6404).

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/pull/7558*</sup>

---

The documentation, that was reading:

> If left empty, being omitted, or being set to `null`, the `option` will be placed before the first `section`.
> Using `null` is also required if the config format does not support sections.

Will read, in its updated version:

> If being omitted, the `option` will be placed before the first `section`.
> Omitting `section` is also required if the config format does not support sections.

<sup>*Reference: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/pull/7558/files*</sup>

So, since just omitting the `section` is acceptable too, now, just do not include it in your task:

```yaml
- name: Ensure fav=juice is in file
  community.general.ini_file:
    path: /home/lab/test.conf
    option: fav
    value: juice
```

Comment: Of course i did try to omit the "section" completely when I asked the question.. I got the error message  "msg": "missing required arguments: section"

Comment: You're probably in an odd situation where your `community.general` collection is lagging behind and not yet supporting it, still you have a more recent verision of `ansible-core`. Please do share your `community.general` version.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your replies. My installation had community.general collection version 6.3.0 and hence I was getting error 'missing required argument section'. This [comment](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/6708#issuecomment-1596231893) recommends version 6.6.0 or later. So I ran the upgrade collection command

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general -U
```

which upgraded my community.general collection to version 8.0.2. After this upgrade, running the playbook without the section, did not throw error and worked as expected.